# Count number of items in a column using Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
SELECT
  *, (SELECT count(1) FROM unnest(A.b)) AS cnt
FROM A
```

In Table A, I am trying to count the number of items in column b containing a list of items. The query above works, but I am trying to write a sqlalchemy query as below, but it doesn't work. How can I write the query in sqlalchemy?

`session.query(A, func.count(func.unnest(A.b)).label('cnt'))`

Thanks in advance! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

In core the query would be

```py
# t is the Table
subq = (
    sa.select(sa.func.count())
    .select_from(sa.func.unnest(t.c.b))
    .scalar_subquery()
)
q = sa.select(t, subq.label('cnt')).select_from(t)
```

The ORM equivalent is

```py
with Session() as s:
    subq = (
        s.query(sa.func.count())
        .select_from(sa.func.unnest(A.b))
        .scalar_subquery()
    )
    q = s.query(A, subq.label('cnt')).select_from(A)
```

Comment: The resulting query from q from the code was `SELECT *, cnt.count_1 AS cnt_count_1 FROM A, (SELECT count(*) AS count_1 FROM unnest(A.b)) AS cnt` which is not correct.

Comment: subq worked fine as it showed `SELECT count(*) AS count_1
FROM unnest(A.b)`.

Comment: There seems missing piece between subq and q..

Comment: I've double-checked and the code in the answer produces the expected SQL for me; [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WwqWq913).